# MongoDB: Updating a document (create one if such document doesn't exists and then update)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to update a document(push a json object) matched by an "id", but if that document doesn't exists, create one(with the same structure) followed by the same update(push) to that document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the update command with the upsert option:

```
db.yourCollection.update({id:xxx}, {id:xxx, field1:yyy, field2:zzz}, {upsert:true})
```

The first parameter is the search query and should be done on a uniquely indexed field.  The second is the actual document to insert/update and the third tells it to do an upsert.

Answer (score 0):

> db.yourCollection.update({id:xxx}, {id:xxx, field1:yyy, field2:zzz},
>   {upsert:false})

```
upsert is a Optional. If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria. If set to false, which does not insert a new document when no match is found.
```